# ASP.NET MVC Multi Tenant Application Questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, multi-tenant

We are currently developing an asp.net mvc3 (aspx) multi tenant website.  We have created a tenant configuration section in our web.config w/ the following structure:

```
<tenants>
  <tenant name="client1" baseUrl="client1.domain.com">
    <settings>
      <setting name="siteName" value="client 1 site">
    </settings>
  </tenant>
  <tenant name="client2" baseUrl="client2.domain.com">
    <settings>
      <setting name="siteName" value="client 2 site">
    </settings>
  </tenant>
</tenants>
```

And in our code we have more or less a tenant builder that creates concrete classes from our ITenant interface.

Everything works well rendering our site per tenant once we are able to resolve it.  However I don't feel comfortable the way were are doing two things. *Also note while we are doing Dependency Injection we are not using a 3rd party IOC Container (all DI is custom right now).*

1. Controller action overrides - currently we have some methods in our tenants that act as controller action overrides (returns an ActionResult) that are called in the actual controller action.  For example - If we needed tenant specific logic for Home/Index we would do something like this:  return currentTenant.HomeIndex().  **Rather than do it this way, can I use a ControllerFactory or the ServiceLocator?  If so can someone explain the best way to go about this?**
2. Access - right now our two tenants equate to the following:  client1 = free user, client2 = paid user.  **While we use a MembershipProvider to authorize users, we have created an ActionFilter that checks the user type/level and continue or redirect to the appropriate site.  Is there a smarter way to do these checks?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can have an extra variable at the action declaration, ie:

```
public ActionResult Index(Itenant tenant)
```

and instead of return currentTenant.HomeIndex() you could do

```
return Action("Index", new { tenant = currentTenant});
```

which would automagically work. (Or you could skipe the new {tenant.. } part, and use a custom model binder if you feel extra adventurous!)

Second part, this is actually the smarter way. If you want custom security clearance with redirection, you have to implement a custom filter.